# 4k monitor and upscaled display to improve text legibility in Windows 11

Tags: 4k-resolution, cleartype

Is my thinking correct that a **4k monitor** /similar physical size to my current 1080p/ **upscaled to 200%** in system settings will give me the same size of displayed content but with **way** **better quality** of text?

Logically the same physical inch on the monitor would be displayed with four times the number of pixels so the quality of antialiased letters should be finer...

Comment: Perhaps, and perhaps not... I find Cleartype antialiasing of limited value., particularly for some fonts (e.g., a narrow sans serif), which even with multiple attempts at optimization, look bad at some zoom settings. You'd have to try it with *your* preferred fonts to see if it improves appearance. That said, 4k lets you see images in much higher detail.

Comment: I used to disable CT and enable it only for the moment I launch the web browser to have a genuine preview of the site I'm working on but such workflow is cumbersome. Windows could learn a lot from Gnome in this respect. In Ubuntu the legibility of even small labels is so much better. Windows makes the impression of being a Frankenstein of different teams and ideas over the years - it lacks aesthetic cohesion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those with similar dilemmas as mine - similar physical size, 4k and scaling Windows display is the way to go. I've switched from FHD z23n HP to 4K U28 HP, rescaled to the recommended 150% and the difference in text rendering is overwhelming plus I have some more workspace for my tools (at 100% things are too tiny, even on 32 inch which I tried and returned as it's physically too bulky on my desk). If you code a lot and need crisp, clear text at small sizes don't hesitate to change your monitor. I've strained my vision for too long reading blurry ugly ghost letters. Now it looks like in a smartphone (where PPI is even higher).

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can see at 4k+ resolutions Windows 10 doesn't show fonts (using Cleartype) the way it does on lower resolutions. It looks like Windows "tries to do the best" but letters are obviously thinner on 4k+ monitors (at any general scaling factor). So it looks like scaling works great for the general size of the letter but not for the letter's thickness.
It's very inconvinient for me personally. At my work (Word/Excel) QHD looks much better solution than 4k (at least on 27" monitor). I had to move myself to 4k 32" - on this monitor size thinner fonts is a small problem.

I hope that Windows 11 (maybe) has better Cleartype algorithm for 4k monitors but I had no chance to check it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Maybe it's up to your GPU or drivers? Have you checked if the problem occurs on another hardware? I haven't noticed any thickness problem TBH.. Now I'm running RTX3050 & Win11 on HP U28 with the recommended150% scale and finally it's just perfect;)